# Sending messages to rabbit mq using lisp inside a docker container

Tags: rabbitmq, common-lisp, amqp, sbcl, docker-compose

I am attempting to use cl-rabbit to communicate with the RabbitMQ broker from a lisp process running inside a Docker container.  I have code that works when I run it outside a docker container, so the problem is either related to the OS or Docker.  (It runs on Mac OS X outside the container, but Ubuntu 14.04 inside the container.)

When I run the system with `docker-compose up`, I see output that the message broker has started successfully.  The lisp client gives this output:

```
sbcl-rabbit_1 | This is SBCL 1.2.15, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
sbcl-rabbit_1 | More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.
sbcl-rabbit_1 |
sbcl-rabbit_1 | SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
sbcl-rabbit_1 | It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
sbcl-rabbit_1 | BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
sbcl-rabbit_1 | distribution for more information.
sbcl-rabbit_1 | Created connection #<CL-RABBIT::CONNECTION {10047054F3}>
sbcl-rabbit_1 | Created socket #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00651650)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | Opened socket #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00651650)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | CORRUPTION WARNING in SBCL pid 10(tid 140737354065728):
sbcl-rabbit_1 | Memory fault at 0x7ffff266ce10 (pc=0x7ffff2c957c2, sp=0x7ffff309f3d0)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | The integrity of this image is possibly compromised.
sbcl-rabbit_1 | Continuing with fingers crossed.
sbcl-rabbit_1 | Unhandled SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD
sbcl-rabbit_1 |                                                 "main thread" RUNNING
sbcl-rabbit_1 |                                                  {1003FAF093}>:
sbcl-rabbit_1 |   Unhandled memory fault at #x7FFFF266CE10.
sbcl-rabbit_1 |
sbcl-rabbit_1 | Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1003FAF093}>
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 0: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SB-DEBUG::FUNCALL-WITH-DEBUG-IO-SYNTAX))
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 1: (SB-IMPL::CALL-WITH-SANE-IO-SYNTAX #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SB-DEBUG::FUNCALL-WITH-DEBUG-IO-SYNTAX) {10047B016B}>)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 2: (SB-IMPL::%WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN SB-DEBUG::FUNCALL-WITH-DEBUG-IO-SYNTAX) {10047B013B}>)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 3: (PRINT-BACKTRACE :STREAM #<SYNONYM-STREAM :SYMBOL SB-SYS:*STDERR* {1000164243}> :START 0 :FROM :INTERRUPTED-FRAME :COUNT NIL :PRINT-THREAD T :PRINT-FRAME-SOURCE NIL :METHOD-FRAME-STYLE NIL)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 4: (SB-DEBUG::DEBUGGER-DISABLED-HOOK #<SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR {10047ACE93}> #<unavailable argument>)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 5: (SB-DEBUG::RUN-HOOK *INVOKE-DEBUGGER-HOOK* #<SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR {10047ACE93}>)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 6: (INVOKE-DEBUGGER #<SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR {10047ACE93}>)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 7: (ERROR SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR :ADDRESS 140737260211728)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 8: (SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 9: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 10: ("foreign function: post_signal_tramp")
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 11: (CFFI::PREPARE-FUNCTION "amqp_login_with_properties" (:STRUCT CL-RABBIT::AMQP-RPC-REPLY-T) (:POINTER :POINTER :INT :INT :INT :POINTER :INT :POINTER :POINTER) :DEFAULT-ABI)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 12: (CL-RABBIT::AMQP-LOGIN-SASL-PLAIN-WITH-PROPERTIES #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00641500) "/" 0 131072 0 #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X7FFFF329FFE8) 0 "guest" "guest")
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 13: ((LABELS #:FN274 :IN CL-RABBIT:LOGIN-SASL-PLAIN) (CL-RABBIT::NUM-ENTRIES 2 CL-RABBIT::ENTRIES #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00651840)))
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 14: (CL-RABBIT::CALL-WITH-AMQP-TABLE #<CLOSURE (LABELS #:FN274 :IN CL-RABBIT:LOGIN-SASL-PLAIN) {100470785B}> (("product" . "cl-rabbit") ("version" . "0.1")))
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 15: (CL-RABBIT.EXAMPLES::TROY-TEST)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 16: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (CL-RABBIT.EXAMPLES::TROY-TEST) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 17: (EVAL (CL-RABBIT.EXAMPLES::TROY-TEST))
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 18: (SB-IMPL::PROCESS-EVAL/LOAD-OPTIONS ((:LOAD . "examples.lisp") (:EVAL . "(sleep 3)") (:EVAL . "(cl-rabbit.examples::troy-test)") (:QUIT)))
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 19: (SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-INIT)
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 20: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-83 :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
sbcl-rabbit_1 | 21: ((LABELS SB-IMPL::RESTART-LISP :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
sbcl-rabbit_1 |
sbcl-rabbit_1 | unhandled condition in --disable-debugger mode, quitting
```

The stack trace seems to indicate something like a bad pointer reference inside the RabbitMq-C code.

To build the docker images, used this file to create an sbcl image:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install things needed to get and install sbcl and quicklisp
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y wget make pkg-config gcc libffi-dev
# Install sbcl
RUN cd /usr/local && \
    wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/sbcl/sbcl-1.2.15-x86-64-linux-binary.tar.bz2 && \
    tar xf sbcl-1.2.15-x86-64-linux-binary.tar.bz2 && \
    cd sbcl-1.2.15-x86-64-linux && \
    ./install.sh
# Install quicklisp
RUN wget https://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp && \
    yes "" | sbcl --load quicklisp.lisp \
                  --eval '(quicklisp-quickstart:install)' \
                  --eval '(ql:quickload "vecto")' \
                  --eval '(ql:add-to-init-file)'\
                  --non-interactive

# Mount workspace
WORKDIR /app

# Run sbcl
CMD sbcl
```

That is build with `docker build -f Dockerfile-sbcl -t sbcl`.  I then have a second docker file to build an image with cl-rabbit.

```
# SBCL with cl-rabbit installed
FROM sbcl

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y librabbitmq-dev

ENV SBCL_CORE_DIR=/sbcl


RUN mkdir -p $SBCL_CORE_DIR
RUN sbcl --eval '(ql:quickload :cl-rabbit)' \
         --eval '(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die "/'${SBCL_CORE_DIR}'/sbcl-rabbit.core")'

RUN echo Saved core in $SBCL_CORE_DIR
RUN ls -l $SBCL_CORE_DIR

CMD sbcl --core $SBCL_CORE_DIR/sbcl-rabbit.core \
    --non-interactive                           \
    --load examples.lisp                        \
    --eval '(sleep 3)'                          \
    --eval '(cl-rabbit.examples::troy-test)'

#CMD ls -l
# EOF
```

This is built using `docker-compose build` with this docker-compose.yml.

```
sbcl-rabbit:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-sbcl-rabbitmq
  volumes:
   - ../../path/to/lisp://app
  links:
   - msgbroker


msgbroker:
  image: rabbitmq
  ports:
   - "5672:5672"
```

When I run this with `docker-compose up`, I get the output described above.

Examples.lisp is the following:

```
(require 'cl-rabbit)
(in-package :cl-rabbit.examples)

(defvar msgbroker "msgbroker")
;;(setq msgbroker "localhost")

(defun troy-test ()
  (with-connection (conn)
    (format t "Created connection ~s~%" conn)
    (let ((socket (tcp-socket-new conn))
          (channel 1))
      (format t "Created socket ~s~%" socket)
      (socket-open socket msgbroker 5672)
      (format t "Opened socket ~s~%" socket)
      (login-sasl-plain conn "/" "guest" "guest")
      (format t "logged in ~s~%" conn)
      (channel-open conn channel)
      (format t "Openned channel ~s~%" conn)
      (queue-declare conn channel
                     :queue "lisp-queue"
                     :durable t)
      (exchange-declare conn channel "lisp-exchange" "direct"
                        :durable t)
      (queue-bind conn channel
                  :queue "lisp-queue"
                  :routing-key "lisp-queue"
                  :exchange "lisp-exchange")
      (print "Bound queue")
      (basic-publish conn channel
                     :exchange "lisp-exchange"
                     :routing-key "lisp-queue"
                     :body "Message from lisp")
      (print "Pubished");
      (basic-consume conn channel "lisp-queue")
      (print "Received")
      (let* ((result (consume-message conn))
             (message (envelope/message result))
             (formatted (format t "Got message: ~s~%content: ~s~%props: ~s"
                                result (babel:octets-to-string (message/body message) :encoding :utf-8)
                                (message/properties message))))
        (prin1 formatted)
        (pprint formatted)
        (cl-rabbit:basic-ack conn channel (envelope/delivery-tag result))))))
```

Based on the print statements, the problem is happening in `login-sasl-plain`.

I have used `docker run rabbit_sbcl-rabbit bash` to start the Docker container with an interactive shell, and verified, using `telnet msgbroker 5672`, that port 5672 on host msgbroker does connect to the rabbit MQ server.  If I type text into the telnet session, I see a message from the server that an AMQP connection has been made.

I do not see a similar message when the lisp client attempts to connect.

Using a similar configuration, I have used a Java client to send and receive messages, with the sender and receiver being in one Docker container, and the RabbitMQ server in a different one, as I am attempting here.

Any idea what is going wrong, or further suggestions on things to do to try to diagnose it?

Comment: Perhaps it's worth trying in a regular ubuntu vm? Perhaps spin up a vagrant instance and try it in there? If you get the same error, that may make it a little easier to debug. If not, well... You've ruled out a complete inability to run it on linux, anyway, and maybe you'll get something else useful... Here's hoping.

Comment: Note that the guest:guest user can only connect to localhost https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you still have troubles try to build sbcl with statically linked librabbitmq and libffi.

Also you may find my project helpful - https://github.com/cl-rabbit/cl-bunny/